# How to rotate map to north

Tags: android, skmaps

How can I make the map turn towards north in skmaps?

I'm using skmaps of 3.0.3 version and it doesn't have 
SKMapSurfaceView.rotateTheMapToNorth() method in it. I've looked for ways for turning it north.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the bearing on your SKMapSurfaceView.

```
mapView.animateToBearing(0f, true, 1000)
```